# Strange snmpd traffic

Tags: centos7, snmp, snmpd

my snmp server is using 3% of CPU and about 600 kbit/s of bandwidth.

Using "iftop" my server is sending data to an unknown IP, in HTTP port, but the destination IP does not ping and has no HTTP port open.

```
myhostname.com.br:snmp                          => 144.168.68.43:http                                   520Kb   487Kb   487Kb
                                                <=                                                     40.2Kb  37.6Kb  37.6Kb
```

All defaults (snmpd.conf), I just use it to local MRTG.

It's a CentOS 7 under OpenVZ. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, first of all never expose snmp publicly, get some firewall rules in place.

Comment: Snmpd is bind to 127.0.0.1 and blocked using iptables (udp in). This is outgoing connection, from my server to this IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these notifications/traps, or responses to Get requests?

---

#### Responses

Someone is polling your SNMP service, it's as simple as that.

If you don't want them to do that, firewall them (or it) off.

It's common for public services to be polled by random strangers, sometimes as a result of an automated probe but sometimes for explicitly malicious purposes. That's why we have firewalls.

Neither ICMP ping nor HTTP has anything to do with it; SNMP responses go to the same address (IP & port) that the requests came from — the choice of port is effectively arbitrary, but it would seem that the originator has specifically decided to use port 80 because this is commonly an open port, and does not draw much attention. This in itself is frankly suspicious because, unless there are strange technical constraints, an authentic and authorised SNMP manager would be using a port more conventionally allocated to SNMP traffic (like UDP 162).

---

#### Traps (notifications)

If there is no evidence of incoming requests triggering this traffic, then your SNMP Agent is doing this on its own. Did you configure it to do so? If not, you may have been hacked and somebody else has configured it this way instead.

You can still firewall it off (the firewall goes both ways!) though you really should be checking into what happened.

---

#### Otherwise

If there are no requests incoming, and your SNMP manager is not configured to send notifications to 144.168.68.43, then do you have *another* SNMP manager you're not aware of? Some piece of software you installed that has SNMP support? Otherwise you're really in trouble.

Comment: No, firewall is closed. The traffic is from my server (outgoing).

Comment: @Arvy If it were closed, the requests would not be getting through. If you're saying that your agent is dispatching SNMP notifications (as opposed to responses to a Get request) then either your config is wrong or you have been hacked.

Comment: I found, it's something related to MIB, reading something. I really don't understand snmp well, I don't know what the server is trying to read from internet.

Comment: MIB definitions don't autonomously trigger SNMP requests. If you can provide a packet capture we'll at least know what the traffic _is_, though that likely won't tell us _why_.

Comment: After a reboot, the problem is fixed. I'll monitor. Thanks.

Comment: Just an additional information, before the problem, iptables was stopped. I forgot to auto-start it on reboot (chkconfig). Even it was bind to 127.0.0.1, something was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. This IP is related to MIB, reading something from an unreachable IP.

If I block it (iptables), "journal" starts to log every 2-3 seconds:

```
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]: send response: Failure in sendto
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.2
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.3
Nov 19 10:33:44 loki snmpd[18942]:     -- SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0
(....)
```

I just don't know how to fix... at least, server is not compromissed.

Comment: The log seems clear: someone is polling your snmpd. Your server IS likely compromised. You have not proven your assertion "Snmpd is bind to 127.0.0.1 and blocked using iptables (udp in)" with netstat -an or iptables.

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      427/snmpd
    udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:161             0.0.0.0:*                           427/snmpd

Comment: At least these are responses, not notifications

Comment: Arvy, showing that it listens on 127.0.0.1 DOES NOT prove that it does not listen on other ports. What does this say "netstat -an | grep :161"?

Comment: Only udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:161             0.0.0.0:* - anyway, after the reboot, no more strange traffic detected.